# Transition and transform at the same time?

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` with a `background-image` and a `height` of `100px`.  I would like to make it so that on hover, the div will transform from `100px` to `300px`.  and the background image will transition into place over `1s` for both properties.

I have the background image working perfectly, and when I apply the transformation to the `height` of the `<div>`, it works, but the background image stops working; rather, it is already at its final placement, without a transition.

Can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You need to better explain yourself. Nobody wants to answer a "Gimme teh codez" question

Comment: what i am asking is, is it possible to use transform (of height) and transition (of background image) of the same element at the same time?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. But to ask a question that will receive a quality answer you need to explain everything you have done, possibly provide a jsfiddle, ect.

Comment: background-position: -350px 0px;
 transition: background-position 1s;
 -moz-transition: background-position 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
 -webkit-transition: background-position 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
 -o-transition: background-position 1s; /* Opera */

Comment: Don't put code in comments. It's just... not right. :-)

Comment: Either edit your answer to include what you have tried, or put it in a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/m7hHg/

```
div {
 background-image:url("http://www.whitegadget.com/attachments/pc-wallpapers/130360d1359002342-background-image-background-image-image-1024x768.jpg");/*Insert your image here*/
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s;
 -moz-transition:all 1s;
 -o-transition:all 1s;
 -ms-transition:all 1s;
 transition:all 1s;
}
div:hover {
 background-position:-350px 0;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}
```

The problem with your code is that you were only specifying the background-position on the transition. By using `all` instead of `background-position`, you are telling the CSS to say "If there is a style change by `hover`, `active`, etc., change every style with a transition." You only specify if you only want that one property to be animated